# How to interrupt a process and continue it later?

Tags: c, linux, signals, fork

i want to try to program a small shell on my own, because it is a nice way to learn signals.
But somehow i have some problems to suspend a process and also continue it later.

`execute_command()` should be the interesting part, because before i'm only splitting the inputted information.

```
void execute_command(){

    int status = 0;
    pid_t childprocess= fork();
    int wait_state=0;
    if(arg_list[0] == NULL){
        exit(0);
    }

    if(childprocess  <0 ){
        printf(" Could not create childprocess");
    }else if (childprocess == 0){
        int end_state =execvp(*arg_list,arg_list);

        if(end_state < 0){
            printf("Some kind of Error happens here \n");
        }else if(end_state == 0){
        //  printf("Program exited with %d\n",end_state);
        }
            exit(0);
    }else{
        current_process_id = childprocess;
        register_signals();
                    last_pid = getpid();

                    /*When i have found a '&' */
        if(!background_process){
            do{
                waitpid(childprocess,&status,WUNTRACED);
                if( WIFSTOPPED(status) ) {
                                        // later for conitinuing the suspended process
                    last_pid = childprocess;
                                        kill(last_pid,SIGSTOP); // edited line of code !
                }
            }while( !WIFEXITED(status) && !WIFSIGNALED(status));
        }
    }
}

void register_signals(){
    signal(SIGINT,signal_int_handler);
    signal(SIGTSTP,signal_stop_handler);
}
```

mysignal.c:

```
void signal_int_handler(int signum){
    printf("[caught SIGINT]\n");
} 
void signal_kill_handler(int signum){
}

void signal_stop_handler(int signum){
printf("[caught SIGTSTP]\n");
}
```

When i press "Ctrl+z" the signal_action execute and print the message from the command signal_stop_handler.
But the program is still running in the do-while-loop.
Maybe i have misunderstood something.

My test input is : `sleep 50`

I only want to suspend a process and also continue it later.

Can someone give me a hint?

Edit: i have edit the code, depend on the answer, but it doesn't works

Answer (score 0):

If you catch `SIGTSTP` in your program, it won't be suspended. Suspend is its default behavior and it goes away once a custom handler is installed. There is also `SIGTSTOP` which can't be diverted and suspends the process in all cases.

Comment: So you mean i have to call `kill(pid,SIGSTOP)` to my Prozess in the `signal_stop_handler`  ?

Comment: i have tried this, but after sending `kill(last_pid,SIGSTOP) `my process ist still hanging in the do-while loop :/
 Maybe i follow the wrong logic?